problems in Read \ write buffers to a serial port with PowerShell
I have A script in PowerShell that read date from a serial port of a device.
in some cases I write (send the port data) according to the input.
e.g.
Device : Enter Name :
I write: Gil
Device : Enter Age :
I Write: 30
...
In some cases I see that the read buffer is giving me back data that I sent to the write buffer.
can you help
I Use ReadChar()
I tried ReadLine() but did not know how to deal with lines without a Newline (CR+LF)

You can't readline until the entire receive message occur.  Are you reading text or binary?  How do you know when you get the entrire message.  Usually text will end with a known character.  The know character may not be a return. Binary you will need a byte count at beginning of the message.

This would we a lot easier if you posted the code you're asking about :)

"In some cases I see that the read buffer is giving me back data that I sent to the write buffer." - That sounds like your script is receiving "echo". Echo can be performed on the local side and/or performed by the remote device. You need to check the settings of both sides (of the serial link) to see if echo is enabled.
